# How to Format Open XML Decimal Values in C# using the OPEN XML SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml-sdk

I have a scenario in an MVC application where I cam using OPEN XML for real excel file and then display list in a table view, The decimal values with precision point do not get read and formatted correctly, I have tried multiple conversions but seem to not work. I am attempting to format it to a 2 decimal places, I attempted using Math.Round but it doesn't seem to work. Please see my code below: This is on the Total Claim column value in  my excel sheet.

```
private static CleanSupplierClaim MappExcelOpenXMLtoGenericList(IList<string> rowData, IList<string> columnNames)
    {

        var cleanSupplierClaims = new CleanSupplierClaim()
        {
            Action = rowData[columnNames.IndexFor("Action")],
            Line_Number = rowData[columnNames.IndexFor("Lineno")],
            Total_Claim = rowData[columnNames.IndexFor("TotalClaim")].ToDecimalNullable(), //Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(rowData[columnNames.IndexFor("TotalClaim")].ToDoubleNullable()),2)),

            Currency = rowData[columnNames.IndexFor("Currency")],
            ClaimReference = rowData[columnNames.IndexFor("ClaimReference")]
        };

        return cleanSupplierClaims;
    }
```

Here is my generic class to read cell values:

```
    private static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
{
    if (cell == null) return null;
    string value = cell.InnerText;

    //Process values particularly for those data types.
    if (cell.DataType != null)
    {
        switch (cell.DataType.Value)
        {
            //Obtain values from shared string table.
            case CellValues.SharedString:
                var sstPart = document.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();
                value = sstPart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText.Trim();
                break;

            //Optional boolean conversion.
            case CellValues.Boolean:
                var booleanToBit = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BooleanToBit"];
                if (booleanToBit != "Y")
                {
                    value = value == "0" ? "FALSE" : "TRUE";
                }
                break;

            case CellValues.Number:
                return Convert.ToDecimal(cell.CellValue.Text).ToString();
            default:
                if (cell.CellValue != null)
                    return cell.CellValue.Text;
                return string.Empty;

        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

All the formatting I have attempted either skips the value with decimals or it returns the value as 0, it works fine for whole numbers, please assist.

This is in MVC Application using VS 2013 and OPEN XML

Comment: What does the decimal string look like? I bet it has something to do with `.` or `,`

Comment: It has a comma as you specified. Here is an example of a value 85,7703 and 292,28. This value gets formatted to something like this 292,288888888888. How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh I thought you didn't get a decimal value at all, just use `Convert.ToDecimal(cell.CellValue.Text).ToString("F")`

Comment: @AlexanderDerck for some reason on my local machine it returns 0 for the multi decimal values and when I deploy to server it appears as 292,288888888888, Any idea why that is?

Comment: Probably the culture of your machine, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx), if you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` the `.` is the decimal seperator and `,` thousands separator.